# How to sort each numerical value in a number?

Tags: php, sorting, numbers

I am making a PHP login/register form and to confirm whether someone is actually human and not a bot I am generating a random value that has to be written in a certain way.
For example:

Please write the following number in an increasing manner: 34745
The user should write 34457 and only then will the confirmation work.

The thing is I know how to use the rand() function, that's how I generate the number. But the problem is I do not know how to make PHP sort the generated number's numerical values (for ex.: 64348 -> 34468).
How do I do this? I hope there is a single function for that, as I've seen numerous ways to sort arrays and since they have indexes I only suppose that it should be possible to sort a number's values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$number = str_split("647214");

sort($number);
$number = implode($number);

echo $number;

?>
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/RepImd

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an integer to hold the complete number you could create an array of size n (n is the number of digits). Iterate over the array and use rand() to create random numbers from 0-9 in each position of the array. Now you have an array which can be sorted by using standard sort functions.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it has single function, but you can make this.

```
   $num = 34745;
   $chars = preg_split('/ /', $num, -1, PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

   sort($chars);

   $res = implode("", $chars);
   echo $res;
```

I didn't tested this, but I hope it works!

Comment: Another user has posted a similar example. Thanks to you both!